# Escape & symbol in MailTo

Tags: java, html, spring, escaping, mailto

I have a URL like this: http://localhost:9001/view/shopindex/display?keyword=test&searchPostcode=Postcode and I'm putting it in the body of a new email message using HTML mailTo (I know that there are better options to mailTo but I'm restricted to this). Effectively I have this:

```
<a href="mailto: ?subject=Look at this link&amp;body=http://localhost:9001/view/shopindex/display?keyword=test&amp;searchPostcode=Postcode"></a>
```

The problem is that when I click and I get the new e-mail message opened, I get only the following in the body:

http://localhost:9001/view/shopindex/display?keyword=test

I think the `mailto` is identifying the `&` symbol in the query string of the web page URL as part of the mailto URL. Is there a way I can escape it?

Thanks!

Krt_Malta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try URL-encoding the ampersand character instead:

```
http://localhost:9001/view/shopindex/display?keyword=test%26searchPostcode=Postcode
```

It works fine for me in Firefox, you can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sXbb9/).

Comment: Yes worked 10x :) I used this in my controller: m.put("url", URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8"));