# Best way to encode URL in Java

Tags: java, uri, url-encoding

HI guys,

I have a URL and I want to embed it in the body of a `mailto`. Till now, I've tried 2 methods to encode the URL and both of them did not give me good results:

`URLEncoder` - this gave me plus signs in the e-mail message since apparently URLEncoder is appropriate for query parameters only.

`org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI` - this doesn't give me the complete URL. It gives me the same results as I had explained in a post earlier here: [Escape & symbol in MailTo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288527/escape-symbol-in-mailto)

What can I do?

Thanks :)
Krt_Malta

Comment: Can you please be more explicit on the URL returned with the 2 methods you tried an the original URL?

Answer (score 6):

How about using `URIUtil` from `httpclient`?

```
URIUtil.encodeQuery(strUrl, "UTF-8");
```

Encoding the following address `mailto:jo han.sjoberg@m.com` gives `mailto:jo%20han.sj%C3%83%C2%B6berg@m.com`

Technically though, both `+` and `%20` are acceptable encoding for a whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Since spaces are converted to `+`, would it be sufficient to just replace all instances of `+` with `%20` in the body?

```
mailto: ?subject=Look at this link&amp;body=Check%20out%20this%20too%20http://localhost:9001/view/shopindex/display?keyword=test%26searchPostcode=Postcode"
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/xzpu2/1/)