# URL Encoding in Java Mail

Tags: java, url, encoding

I have written a code in java, where there are forms (input fields) and finally a send email button at the bottom. when the user clicks on the button, the data from the input fields should get extracted then be used as data for the body in the email.

this is the code i have:

```
if (role.getValue().equals("1")) {          
    Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
    String message = "mailto:username@domain.com?subject=Profildaten&body=" +
                     "Externe%20Referenz:%20" +
                     person.getExternalReference() + "%20" + "-%20" +
                     person.getExternalReferenceType() + "%0A" +
                     person.getTitle() + "%20" +
                     person.getContactLandline() + "%0A" +
                     "Mobil:%20" + person.getContactMobile() + "%0A" +
                     "Addresse:" + person.getContactStreet();

    URI uri = URI.create(message); 
    try {
        desktop.mail(uri);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

It all works perfectly, but the only issue is for Address: person.getContactStreet() the actual input field requires the user to enter a street name, and usually it would be two words, e.g. Cromwell Road - with a space inbetween cromwell and road. now the body of the email doesnt allow to have spaces and other invalid characters, hence why it is popping an error message saying invalid characters have been entered. how can i make it accept this or convert the invalid characters automatically to url encodings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at this site, it tells you how to encode the URLS in the body automatically.

[Best way to encode URL in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291586/best-way-to-encode-url-in-java)

Comment: I am not too clear how to do it because. It does say in forums, that I can just replace the space with a + or %20. However, if the user manually inputs data into the fields, i cant get him to do this. the user will be entering data normally with spaces, but this wont be accepted by the program though. what way is there around it?

Comment: Using the details on the link provided by Pita Sivam, you can encode the data entered by user on server side and don't have to force the user to enter the data in encoded form.

Comment: @Logan - Yes I have seen the link, but that is a URL Encoder. Is there anything such as a String Encoder, so that input from a user is automatically encoded?

Comment: @Priya Basically what a URL Encoder do is encode a string since URL at base is a String only.